# Parsing a log file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to parse a huge log file. And I would like to do it in Haskell for learning purpose (I am a beginner).
The layout of the log file is something like:

```
parameter a_parameter_name errors: 5
error bla bla1
error bla bla2
error bla bla bla3
error bla bla bla4
error bla bla bla5
some garbage line
parameter an_other_parameter_name errors: 7
error bla bla1
error bla bla2
error bla bla3
error bla bla4
error bla bla5
error bla bla6
error bla bla7

some garbage line
some garbage line
some garbage line
...
```

This log file contains 2 main line types:

1. lines starting by "parameter";
2. lines starting by "error".

The "error" lines are related to the previous parameter line.
The other lines are not interesting.

What I would like to do is to print out the parameters and their errors, ordered by the number of errors. So here I would like to get:

```
parameter an_other_parameter_name errors: 7
error bla bla1
error bla bla2
error bla bla3
error bla bla4
error bla bla5
error bla bla6
error bla bla7
parameter a_parameter_name errors: 5
error bla bla1
error bla bla2
error bla bla bla3
error bla bla bla4
error bla bla bla5
```

With the following code, I get the list of interesting lines

```
import System.IO
import Data.List

interesting :: String -> Bool
interesting s = isPrefixOf "parameter" s || isPrefixOf "error" s

main = do
    logFile <- openFile "log.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents logFile
    let interestingLines = filter interesting $ lines contents
    print interestingLines
    hClose logFile
```

From this list, I would like to construct a list of triples:
[(parameter, errorsNb, [errors])], which I can sort and print out.
But I have no idea on how to group the error lines with their related parameter line. But perhaps it is not the correct approach ...
Any help is welcome !

Olivier

Comment: There are many options. You could use `span` and explicit recursion to slice the "errors" section. Or you might want `groupBy` to roughly group your list as `[[param1],[err1,err2,err3],[param2],[err4],[param3]]` and then do more processing afterwards to sort that as wanted.

Comment: You should look at using a parsing library for this, for example [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html) makes this kind of work a breeze

Comment: This have some similarity with my question on Code Review, you might want to check [there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147874/kattis-speed-limit-read-irregular-input).

Comment: Thanks you everyone for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my solution of [CIS194](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html)(Week 2). 

Converting to binary Tree data structure and lazy reading from file will be good exercises for learning.

```
type Name = String
type Count = Int
data MessageType =  Param Name Count
                 | Error String
                 | Unknown String
                   deriving (Show, Eq)

parseMessage :: String -> MessageType
parseMessage line =
    case  words line of
      ("parameter":n:_:c:_) -> Param n (read c)
      ("error":msg)         -> Error (unwords msg)
      xs                    -> Unknown $ unwords xs

data LogMessage = LogMessage Name Count [MessageType]
               deriving (Show, Eq)

parse :: String -> [MessageType]
parse = map parseMessage .  lines

isError :: MessageType -> Bool
isError (Error _) = True
isError _ = False


isUnknown :: MessageType -> Bool
isUnknown  (Unknown _)  = True
isUnknown _ = False

(.||.) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
(.||.) f g a = (f a) || (g a)

toLogMsg :: [MessageType] -> [LogMessage]
toLogMsg [] = []
toLogMsg (x:xs) =
    case x of
      Param n c ->
          LogMessage n c (takeWhile isError xs) : toLogMsg (dropWhile (isError .||. isUnknown) xs)
      _         -> toLogMsg $ dropWhile (isError .||. isUnknown) xs



errMsgList :: [MessageType] -> [String]
errMsgList = foldr (\(Error m) acc -> m : acc) []

toTriple :: [LogMessage] -> [(String, Count, [String])]
toTriple = foldl(\acc (LogMessage n c xs) -> (n, c, errMsgList xs) : acc) []



main :: IO ()
main = do
       ts <- toLogMsg . parse <$> readFile "./src/2017/so-log.txt"
       mapM_ print ts
       mapM_ print (toTriple ts)
```

Output of the sample you provide will be:

```
("an_other_parameter_name",7,["bla bla1","bla bla2","bla bla3","bla bla4","bla bla5","bla bla6","bla bla7"])
("a_parameter_name",5,["bla bla1","bla bla2","bla bla bla3","bla bla bla4","bla bla bla5"])


LogTriple "a_parameter_name" 5 [Error "bla bla1",Error "bla bla2",Error "bla bla bla3",Error "bla bla bla4",Error "bla bla bla5"]
LogTriple "an_other_parameter_name" 7 [Error "bla bla1",Error "bla bla2",Error "bla bla3",Error "bla bla4",Error "bla bla5",Error "bla bla6",Error "bla bla7"]
```

Comment: I did not know the CIS194, which seems very interesting. Thanks for the code and for the link!

Comment: could you mark answer as useful or vote for that answer :)